# How to set "aria-hidden" to pseudo-element "::before"?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

There is such a page. For decorative purposes, I add a pseudo-element `::before` for `h2`.

```html
<h2>Title...</h2>
```

```css
h2::before {
    content: "#";
}
```

It will be displayed like this:

**# Title...**

But the screen reader will read "#". It shouldn't be read.

I know `aria-hidden` attribute can skip some element. But how can I use in this case?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634156/can-i-prevent-after-pseudo-element-from-being-read-by-screen-readers) answer your question?

Comment: `speak: none; `

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the content's alt text by adding a / and then the alt, which in your case you'd want an empty string. Example: `content: "#" / ""`

Comment: Don't use `speak: none` support is next to nothing for it. TechyTech has a suggestion [that will work in around 70% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_content_alt_text) so that isn't a bad idea as a quick fix! The best solution would be to use an image (SVG) as a background image using a data URI  and set `content: ""` within your CSS as that will have near perfect support.

Comment: @connexo It doesn't seem to work. I tried and VSCode shown it's an unknown property.

Comment: @HsiaoFeng [Here is a quick fiddle to demo the concept](http://jsfiddle.net/8k4wcb2f/) - the only thing you need to do is convert the SVG to a data URI so that you don't have an unnecessary request,

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thank you! I also think SVG is a better choice.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with the project!